# NSNumberFormatter stringFromNumber should it be able to take a Swift.Int?

Tags: swift, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I noticed today that even though the documentation for `NSNumberFormatter` `stringFromNumber` says that the function declaration takes an `NSNumber` as its argument ...

```
var playerScore = 3456789
let displayScore: String = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(NSNumber.numberWithInteger(playerScore))
```

it also works correctly by simply supplying a `Swift.Int` ...

```
var playerScore = 3456789
let displayScore: String = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(playerScore)
```

Is this the compiler just being clever? or something that should not work. Its things like this that make Swift a little hard to follow at times, especially when its purposely aimed at simplifying things for new developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behaviour. Swift automatically bridges certain native number types, such as `Int` and `Float`, to `NSNumber`.

According to the [Using Swift with Objective-C book](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html), all of the following types are automatically bridged to `NSNumber`:

- `Int`
- `UInt`
- `Float`
- `Double`
- `Bool`

Comment: Reference: ["Working with Cocoa Data Types" in Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html)

Comment: Thanks Martin, just starting on that now.

Comment: Sadly this seems to be broken in Swift 3 :(